# Detect windows os version in shell script

Tags: windows, shell, scripting

Hi Is there a way to determine windows os version in shell script ?

My requirement is

if OS_Version >= win_vista
run cmd1
else
run cmd2

Answer (score 2):

The command to get the version is ver.  Parse the version.txt file then do your compare.

```
C:\>ver >version.txt
C:\>type version.txt
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

Comment: I want it in shell script...not in DOS